# Does reading Line by Line with UrlConnection consider line breaks?

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

Hey there I hope you are able to give me the answer to my question. 
If I read a response after I posted something with my UrlConnection like this:

```
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
  buf.append(line);
}
return(buf.toString());
```

If my response String has line breaks in it, are the line breaks in my *buf.toString()* return? Or are the line breaks lost through the append statement ?

Comment: yes it would consider. Try ti out...

Comment: Thanks @SMA I have a load of changes to do and just wanted to make sure before I start :-)

Comment: *java.io.BufferedReader#readLine* `Returns the next line of text available from this reader. A line is represented by zero or more characters followed by '\n', '\r', "\r\n" or the end of the reader. The string does not include the newline sequence.`

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to keep information if _'n', 'r' or "\r\n"_ was the end of the line so I am able to add this specific character to the line ?

Comment: if you want the whole text (with line break separators) then why do you use `readLine()` method? why not to use `read(char[] buffer, int offset, int length)`?

Answer (score 1):

readLine() only reads contents of line excluding all line ending characters.

```
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
  buf.append(line);
  buf.append("\n"); 
}
```

May be you can change your code to something like this to append line termination characters after every line.

Comment: I tried your method and passed the buf variable to webview textarea and all the data was still in one line and all break lines lost! is there any solution for it  to keep the line breaks?mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:parse('" + buf.toString() + "');");

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below code snippet

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
```

Hope this helps you...
Cheers

Comment: I tried your method and passed the buffer variable to webview textarea and all the data was still in one line and all break lines lost! is there any solution for it to keep the line breaks ?mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:parse('" + buffer.toString() + "');");